# How To Pull Multiple JSON records with one search

Tags: javascript, html, json

In the current DEMO you can search one thing at a time.

If you search either values (1001, 1002, 1003) and a JSON property feature will be pulled.

So if I search: 1001
I get: RANK_BY_CD: 26

I've tired a fuzzy-search library - http://fusejs.io/ but I don't think what is needed since I need a series of EXACT matches

```js
var data = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {
        var searchId = String($('#searchBox').val());
        data.features.forEach(function (any_function_variable_name) {
            if (any_function_variable_name.properties.CDUID == searchId) {
                $("ul")
                 .append('<li> <strong>RANK_BY_CD: </strong>' + any_function_variable_name.properties.RANK_BY_CD);
            }
        });
    });
});

    function getdata() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/6oj58";
        //var data = [];
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    getdata();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="searchBox" type="text"></textarea>
    <button id="button">
        Search
    </button>
    <div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

I want to have the ability to copy paste multiple strings (separated by line break) into the textarea like so:

1001

1002

1003

and get:

RANK_BY_CD: 26

RANK_BY_CD: 212

RANK_BY_CD: 248

Also, I don't want the code to just be limited to these 3 options.

As JSON file gets bigger I want to recognize all the CDUIDs

So a key legend will be inefficient in this case

This is the external JSON file url - https://api.myjson.com/bins/6oj58

Comment: Use a `searchList` and `indexOf` instead of comparing to `searchId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Set` which stores the list of ids and then check that against the `CDUID` of each item in `data.features`:

```js
var data = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function (any_function_variable_name) {
        var searchIds = new Set($('#searchBox').val().split(',').map(s => s.trim()));
        data.features.forEach(({ properties: { CDUID, RANK_BY_CD } }) => {
            if (searchIds.has(CDUID)) {
                $("ul")
                 .append(`<li> <strong>RANK_BY_CD: </strong>${RANK_BY_CD}`);
            }
        });
    });
});

    function getdata() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/6oj58";
        //var data = [];
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    getdata();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="searchBox" type="text"></textarea>
    <button id="button">
        Search
    </button>
    <div>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

[image]